# Fancybox 2.1.5 not working correctly in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari, fancybox

When clicking on an image (one of the cartoons of http://www.hobega.nl/nl/humor which will open the fancybox), the fancybox works correctly on Chrome and Firefox, but Safari puts the fancybox on an incorrect position. Can anyone help with this?

Note; if the page is not working, it might be that I am currently editing. Due to technical issues, it is impossible for me to work offline.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what was the incorrect position? I might have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to unselect this sets of rules in your css, and has worked.

```
:root, *, body, html
{
 -webkit-transition:all 200ms linear;
 -khtml-transition:all 200ms linear;
   -moz-transition:all 200ms linear;
     -o-transition:all 200ms linear;
        transition:all 200ms linear;
}
```

If you add a rule that remove transition at fancybox will work correctly

```
div.fancybox-opened{
     transition:none;
}
```

Comment: Nice, this was it! A friend of mine just happened to have found this same solution. Thanks a lot!